# Problems when rescuing a exception in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Im trying to raise some exceptions on my app, and found a bug that its driving me crazy.

Here is my client code:

```
class PaymentGateway::CreateSubscriptionService < PaymentGateway::Service

def run
    begin
      Subscription.transaction do
        create_client_subscription
        self.subscription = create_subscription
        self.success = true
      end
    rescue PaymentGateway::CreateCustomerService, 
      PaymentGateway::CreatePlanService,
      PaymentGateway::ClientError => e
      raise PaymentGateway::CreateSubscriptionServiceError.new(
        ERROR_MESSAGE,
        exception_message: e.message)
    end
  end
```

My service error:

```
#services/payment_gateway/service_error.rb

class PaymentGateway::ServiceError < StandardError
  attr_reader :exception_message

  def initialize(message, exception_message: )

    super(message)
    @exception_message = exception_message

  end
end
```

My client its:

```
class PaymentGateway::Client
  attr_accessor :external_client

  def initialize(external_client: PaymentGateway::StripeClient.new)
    @external_client = external_client
  end

  def method_missing(*args, &block)
    begin
      external_client.send(*args, &block)
    rescue => e 
      raise PaymentGateway::ClientError.new(e.message)
    end
  end
end

class PaymentGateway::CreateCustomerServiceError < PaymentGateway::ServiceError
end
```

When I run my code, this im getting this error:

ArgumentError in SubscriptionsController#create
    missing keyword: exception_message
    Extracted source (around line #4):

```
  attr_reader :exception_message

  def initialize(message, exception_message: )
```

What Im doing wrong here?

Comment: Remember that `rescue` can be done inside a method without an explicit `begin` surrounding it. The `def` level method acts as the same sort of container.

Comment: Thanks tadman. But I guess it doesnt help me too much

Comment: Do you have a full stack trace here? I'm curious if something else is trying to instantiate your custom exception. Normally you call `raise` in the form `raise ExceptionClass, message, ...` without explicitly calling `new`.

Comment: I will add to the question

Comment: I did a raise PaymentGateway::CreateSubscriptionServiceError,e.message , but the error message its still the same

Comment: What's happening on `client.rb` line 12?

Comment: This should work, like a very minimal version of your code does, but if something else calls `raise PaymentGateway::ServiceError` then all bets are off.

Comment: What is your body of PaymentGateway::CreateSubscriptionServiceError class? I think you call super in a wrong way.

Comment: I will add both (client and CreateSubscriptionServiceError) on the question

Comment: @FernandoMaymone Great

Comment: You defined ```PaymentGateway::CreateCustomerServiceError``` class. However in ```rescue``` section you raised ```PaymentGateway::CreateSubscriptionServiceError``` exception. Can it be a problem?